# An elementary (and soft) question on strict open subschemes of the affine plane.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ringed-spaces

**Question:** A scheme $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a pair where $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of rings on $X$, with the property that there is an open cover $U_i$ of $X$ with $U_i \cong Spec(A_i)$ an affine scheme. It is easy to construct an example of a topological space $X_t$ and a strict open subspace $U_t \subsetneq X_t$ with an abstract homeomorhism $\phi_t: U_t \cong X_t$. Does a similar property hold for a scheme of finite type over a field?

**Example:** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $S:=\mathbb{A}^2_k$ be the affine plane and let $U \subsetneq S$ be a strict open subscheme. Can you give an elementary example of such $U$ where there is an abstract isomorphism $\phi: U \cong S$ of schemes? What about a scheme $X$ of finite type over a field $k$?

As a consequence: If $U_t$ is the topological space of $U$ it follows there is a strict subset $U_t \subsetneq S_t$ with an abstract homeomorphism $\phi_t:U_t  \cong S_t$.

**Note:** Two schemes (or ringed spaces) $(X, \mathcal{O}_X), (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ are "isomorphic" iff there are maps $f:(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y), g:(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)\rightarrow  (X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ with $f\circ g =Id,g \circ f=Id$. In particular the maps $f,g$ induce homeomorphisms of topological spaces $X \cong Y$. If a strict  open subscheme $U \subsetneq V$ is abstractly isomorphic to $V$ you end up with a topological space $U_t \subsetneq V_t$ realizable as a strict subspace of $V_t$, but where there is an abstract isomorphism $U_t \cong V_t$. This stuation is "paradoxical" - the topological space $V_t$ would then be homeomorphic to a strict subspace of itself.

**Example:** For the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ with $k$ an algebraically closed field, it follows there is no abstract isomorphism $\phi: U \cong \mathbb{A}^1_k$ for any strict open subscheme $U \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^1_k$:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A:=k[x]$ be the polynomial ring in one variable $x$ over $k$. Let

$$f(x):=(x-u_1)^{l_1}\cdots (x-u_m)^{l_m}$$

with $u_i \neq u_j\in k$. Let $X:=Spec(A)$ and $U:=D(f) \subsetneq X$ be a strict open subscheme of $X$ and assume $X \cong D(f)$ is an abstract isomorphism of schemes over $k$, induced by a map of $k$-algebras $\tilde{\phi}: A \cong A_f$. The map $\tilde{\phi}$ induce a map of $k$-algebras

$$\phi:k[x] \rightarrow k[x]$$

with $\phi(x)=a(x)$ and $\phi(f(x)):=f(a(x))\in k^*$ a unit. It follows
$\phi(a(x)):=a_0\in k^*$ is a unit with $a_0\neq u_i$ for all $i$. Hence the map $\phi$ factors as follows

$$ k[x] \rightarrow k[x]/(x-a_0) \rightarrow k \subseteq k[x].$$

Hence the induced map $k[x]\rightarrow A_f \rightarrow A$ is the "constant map": The induced map of affine schemes

$$ D(f) \rightarrow X$$

identifies $D(f) \cong \{(x-a_0)\} \subseteq X$ as a topological space with one point which contradicts the assumption that $D(f) \subseteq X$ is an open subscheme.

Hence for the affine line there are no such strict open subschemes. Can you construct such a strict open subscheme $U \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^2_k$  for the affine plane? What about a scheme $X$ of finite type over a field $k$?

**Note:** I post this question to set theorists and algebraic geometers - I want response from both groups of people.

Comment: Hint: The affine space is noetherian.

Comment: No, such $U$ does not exist.

Comment: I can't resist the following comment: the underlying topological space of $\Bbb A^1_k$ for a field $k$ is homeomorphic to an open subspace of itself, because as a set it consists of $|\overline{k}|$ closed points and one generic point, where the closed subsets are finite collections of closed points. Remove one closed point and you get the same thing. So you already deal with such topological spaces every day. (Obviously this does not extend to the scheme version - $k[x]\not\cong k[x]_{f}$, where $f$ picks out the point we remove.)

Comment: @HankScorpio - this is the point - the homeomorphism $X_t \cong U_t$ of the underlying topological spaces should be induced by an abstract isomorphism of schemes $\phi: X \cong U$.

Comment: Why is this a set theory question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila - some people (not all) view it as a "paradox" that an infinite set can be a strict subset of itself.

Comment: But why is this a set theory question? Which part of it depends on inner model theory, forcing, the axiom of choice (in specific interest to the question), or even transfinite recursion? Large cardinal axioms? Diamond and squares? Where does set theory, in a way that makes it relevant to the tag, comes into play in your question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila - in a very "naive" sense: the underlying topological space $U_t$ of a scheme is a set with a topology.

Comment: So what you're saying is that this question has absolutely nothing to do with set theory? In that case, don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - no, not at all. For topological spaces (and "naive" set theory) you may easily construct a strict subspace $U_t \subsetneq X_t$ with $\phi_t:U_t \cong X_t$ homeomorphic. If you require the map $\phi_t$ to be induced by a map of schemes, it seems no such subspace exist. At least for the affine line over an algebraically closed field. Hence the "category of schemes of finite type over a field" differs much from the category of topological spaces.

Comment: You are not listening to me. This is my final comment here. Questions tagged as [tag:set-theory] are questions *about set theory*. Not questions that involve sets. This question is *not* a question about set theory, and therefore has no business having this tag. I'd appreciate it if you don't insist that you know better than me here, since I've been maintaining the content of the set theory tag for a decade now.

Comment: While we're on the topic, I'll point out that this is the most unusual use of "soft question" I've seen around here...

Comment: @AsafKaragila - the question is meant for set-theorists AND algebraic geometers. Please do not interfere with this and do not change the tags - I want response from both groups of people.

Comment: It's fine that you want the input of set-theorists that does not give you the right to use that tag. You mentioned "naive" a couple of times. In that case maybe consider [tag:elementary-set-theory] instead, maybe that could be a compromise.